# Utilizando o .map() Crie uma variável que contenha todas idades dos usuários: [23, 15, 30]

Tags: javascript, node.js

O que foi pedido: Utilizando o .map() Crie uma variável que contenha todas idades dos usuários: [23, 15, 30].
criei o código mas o retorno que tenho é undefined e não sei onde está  erro.

```
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
   ];
const idades = usuarios.map(item =>{
    item = usuarios.idade;
});
console.log(idades);
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce deve retornar `item.idade` pois item representa um objeto dentro da lista usuários

```js
const usuarios = [{
    nome: 'Diego',
    idade: 23,
    empresa: 'Rocketseat'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Gabriel',
    idade: 15,
    empresa: 'Rocketseat'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Lucas',
    idade: 30,
    empresa: 'Facebook'
  },
];
const idades = usuarios.map(item => {
  return item.idade;
});
//ou alternativamente
//const idades = usuarios.map(item => item.idade;);

console.log(idades);
```

Answer (score 2):

Não podes simplesmente mudar o valor de `item`, o método de arrays `.map(` precisa de um retorno para ter o valor substituto para cada posição da array que itera. em vêz de `item =` precisas usar `return`.

Ou seja:

```js
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];
const idades = usuarios.map(item => {
  return item.idade;
});
console.log(idades);
```

Em JavaScript mais comprimido podias fazer assim:

```
const idades = usuarios.map(({idade}) => idade);
```

Exemplo:

```js
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];
const idades = usuarios.map(({idade}) => idade);
console.log(idades);
```